# What is this arch-and-tower near a road?

Tags: international-travel, identify-this

my father took many pictures of this building when I was a child but he is not longer with us so I can’t ask him. 
[image]

Comment: do you know what country or at least what area of the world the picture was taken in?

Comment: As demonstrated by vlumi, in this case a reverse image search with Google or Tineye is more than sufficient, but in cases where the landmark is more obscure, I've found [Where Is This](http://www.where-is-this.com/) to be a brilliant if little-known resource that I've used for several years now. Landmarks are manually identified by users of the site, and from both the site's metrics and my own experience they tend to have a very good ratio of success.

Answer (score 43):

It's the [Azadi Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadi_Tower) in Tehran, Iran.

You can easily use the [Google image search](https://images.google.com) (just drag & drop the file into the browser window when you have it open), which will show many results for such a clear picture.

Comment: If using Chrome: Right Click > *Search Google for Image*

Comment: And in FireFox you can do the same with the [Search by image on Google](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-by-image-on-google/) add-on.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I knew it was famous I just didn’t know where it was. My father loved to travel and take pictures of different buildings and landscapes. Most I knew but this was driving me crazy!! All of your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Ktango01 if you're happy with the answer above, feel free to accept it by clicking the "tick" outline next to it, which puts the question to bed, and drives the reputation system both for you and the author of the answer.